# How to find location of an element in React DOM

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, logic

I am trying to make a spinning wheel(like wheel of fortune or roulette)in react and grab the part of the wheel(8 parts each with a class) that lands next to the fixed arrow.  I have looked at grabbing the offsetHeight and other att's but I cannot find an attribute that gives me its current location after it stops spinning.  So I guess my question is how do I know when say the red part(ex.className="one") of the wheel is lined up with the arrow.  Thanks for all the help.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import './wheelePage.css';


function WheelePage() {
    const [ state, setState ] = useState(false);
    let whenDoneSpin;
    
    
    const spinfn = () => {
        const min = 1024;
        const max = 19999;
        let deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + 4000);
        console.log(deg)
        whenDoneSpin = document.querySelector('.box');
        whenDoneSpin.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`; 
        setTimeout((e) => {
            let panel1 = document.getElementsByClassName("one");
            console.dir(e.screenY)
            console.dir(panel1[0].screenX)
        }, 10000);
    }
    
    var winner = document.getElementsByClassName('large-arrow');
    //console.log(winner)

    return (
        <div className="wheel-container">
            <div className="main-box">
                <div className="box">
                    <div className="box1">
                        <span id="one" className="span1 one">Italian</span>
                        <span id="2" className="span2">Spainish</span>
                        <span id="3" className="span3">America</span>
                        <span id="4" className="span4">Mexican</span>
                    </div>  
                    
                    <div className="box2">
                        <span id="5" className="span1">French</span>
                        <span id="6" className="span2">Eastern European</span>
                        <span id="7" className="span3">Asian</span>
                        <span id="8" className="span4">Southern</span>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>  
                
            <div className="arrow-container">
                <h3 className="large-arrow">↑</h3>
                <button onClick={spinfn} className="spin">Spin</button>
            </div>
        </div>    

    );
}

export default WheelePage;
```

Comment: One thing, `document.*` won't work properly until you've loaded the DOM for client-side, so you'll need to wrap any functions utilizing `document.*` inside of a `useEffect` hook.

As for what you're looking to achieve, the `useRef` hook is what you're looking for.

Here's a link to the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: Can you provide the code with CSS on https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-glitter-oswlo?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: @ElbertBae Im looking into the useRef hooks and they simple pretty straight-forward but do you have any documentation on how to find the location of each element or what property should I use to get the current location. ex. X or Y axis or from-top 100px ?  Thanks again for the info!